# How to find shape/drawing positions in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to read the positions of shapes in my spreadsheet but can't figure out how. I found [this answer](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/jBIS70miMy0;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/authorid$3AAPn2wQc9OU2XfVtc7JNN7QPVDfWHiSSzBugllR5YI7f3Q8gjg7pxWBet6GCByW3qhzmHP4fMxFVO%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false) which says to use the getCharts() function to find drawings but unfortunately it seems to only find charts.

A test spreadsheet I'm using is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b-ViAqW2krnglenEyzzL-PDefSjnLbV0TmJ4_-bZ1I0/edit?usp=sharing). It has three shapes and the function I'm using to get the shapes in the sheet is below, but all it gives is an empty array.

```
function get_shapes() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();

  Logger.log(charts);
}
```

My end goal with this is to be able to move all the shapes in a spreadsheet to the correct positions after a sheet has been sorted. By default the shapes don't seem to move with the rows during a sort in Google Spreadsheets. My plan is to have a script that will record the row positions of all the shapes--> do the sort--> move the shapes to wherever their rows now are.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for using shapes on Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script yet. Recently, several methods for using images were added. But the document of their methods have never published yet. Furthermore, it also confirmed that some methods were modified. It seems that the methods for using images is under development. Although the methods for using images couldn't retrieve shapes, I think that also the methods for using shapes might be added in the future. If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's such a shame! One of the rare times I wish I could do this project in Excel. Where do you get information about what methods are being modified @Tanaike?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I always confirm the information at the official documents of each method and [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/).